# how to use CQ5 fileupload component?

Tags: file-upload, components, aem

I need help regarding file uploading through file. Actually i want to create a form, (using cq5 form component ) in which user can upload a file may be (text or anything) and then  that file will be saved in jcr after clicking submit button. And at the same time user can download that fie from different page.

I have added inbuilt cq5  file upload component  in form, but problem is that , file is not getting saved in jcr.
Please help me how to save file in jcr or how to save reference of file  in jcr.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the action of the form to "Store Content"?, if not, try to do that and set in the advanced properties(they appear after selecting the action) on the Start Form Component dialog with the path you need to store the content. also check the url of the path you're storing the content.

Comment: thank you AJ Oliva for answering the question.Ya i have configured the action path. and i am able to store all data like my name address but files. i can see my data in the path i have specified but i am not able to get the file that i am uploading. please help me. scenario is like this that user will enter all details along with a file in the form and after submitting the form, all details along with that uploaded file will be available in the another page ,from where he can see his details as well as can download the file which he had uploaded using form. please help me achieving this

Comment: have you checked the path of the file for the slashes? I tested using a dummy CQ form in a test page with two text fields and one upload field, and when I submitted the form it created a folder that on its properties are the values of the textfields and under it is a node type nt:file of the file I uploaded, also check where you are uploading the file that could cause problems with permissions